# One of my hard drives is asking for a password that I never set

Tags: linux-mint, hard-disk, password

I am using Linux Mint 20. I was working on my machine and suddenly vscode could not save the file. Then when I restarted my machine it showed the following screen.

[image]

I removed the HDD to boot and posted this question. What is going on? I never set a password for my HDD.

Comment: This might be more appropriate on SO.

Comment: @RonJohn which tags shall I use. I mean, I do not want to get closed during crisis.

Comment: Is this even a Linux problem?  Might it be caused by a malware attack?  Have you googled on how to crack a HDD password?

Comment: @RonJohn to be honest, I am not sure whether it is a linux problem or not. However, I am not sure where to ask this sort of questions.

Comment: I'd start googling on how the HDD password can get mysteriously set, and also how to crack the HDD password.

Comment: @RonJohn yes I am googling for last few minutes.

Comment: @RonJohn I am not liking what I have seen https://community.wd.com/t/wd-essential-password-never-set-one-up-and-now-drive-locked/18724/15 However mine is a Toshiba HDD

Comment: do you have other bootable media (e.g. a live USB)? that looks to me like a bios/uefi password, and if that's the case then it'll appear when trying to boot from anything

Comment: I reset the bios after removing the hdd. Now after attaching the HDD, it is showing `ata2: COMRESET failed (errno= -16)`. `gparted`, `lsblk` not showing the HDD. I will try replacing the sata cable now. Restarting.

Comment: I changed both port and cable. No use. The HDD is making some sound.

Comment: I wonder if it is a failing hard-disk, manifesting errors in a strange way. The hard-disk will have its own operating system ( a simple one ) stored on it self. And will boot it before offering it-self to the host system. Therefore anything could happen it the drive starts failing.  (However that does not explain, how it happened when in use.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has no relation to Unix community. It is a hardware problem away from operating system.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak yes the HDD failed. I took it to a data recovery place. They said the circuit is ok but the head is broken. Hopefully they will be able to recover the data. Shall I delete this question? I am hesitating a little because a lot of community members have given effort here. Thanks to everybody.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor what you said is exactly right. The head is broken but the circuit is ok. your comment is an acceptable answer to me.

Comment: I voted to close as well. I got a tick and an upvote. So hope my vote to close eases your mind. Mostly glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if it is a failing hard-disk, manifesting errors in a strange way. The hard-disk will have its own operating system ( a simple one ) stored on it self. And will boot it before offering it-self to the host system. Therefore anything could happen it the drive starts failing. (However that does not explain, how it happened when in use.